# Start Monitor MSMQ in ASP.NET app start

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a case to convert information from one form to another and its time consuming. I wrote a windows service to do all the conversion. This windows service listens to MSMQ where request messages will be written from ASP.NET app.

Conversion kick starts when user triggers a button click on ASP.NET page. On button click I write to MSMQ which windows service listens to. When it is done with conversion it writes response back to responseMSMQ.

I want to monitor this response MSMQ on my ASP.NET application. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this to read the MSMQ message:

```
private static MyMessage RecieveMessage()
{
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(QueueName))
    {
        return null;
    }

    using (var msmq = new MessageQueue(QueueName))
    {
        msmq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(MyMessage) });
        var message = msmq.Receive();
        return message != null && message.Body is MyMessage ? (MyMessage)message.Body : null;
    }
}
```

What's the exact problem for you? Check a [sample MSMQ project](https://github.com/IvanYurchenko/MSMQSample), maybe it sheds light on how it should be made.